# Venn Diagram for Power Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was wondering what the Venn Diagram for a power set might look like. For example for $\{A, B, C\}$. I'm going to go out on a limb and say it's probably not this:

[image]

However, that image is useful for picturing all the subsets, minus the empty set. Yet from my understanding it shows relationships between 3 sets, rather than within a power set.

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 1):

A well-drawn venn diagram will indeed show every combination of the sets if drawn correctly (*including the emptyset... that is just the area outside of all of the circles in your image*), though doing so can be difficult for beginners for four or more sets at a time (*they won't simply be circles any more*).

A more common way of picturing a power set however is as a [boolean lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)) using [Hasse diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) ordered according to the partial order induced by $\subseteq$.

[image: Hasse diagram for the power set of {x,y,z}]

The lattice corresponding to a powerset is a very well studied object, what we call a "*[Cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube)*" (*or hypercube if you prefer for higher dimensions*).  The notation for this object can vary author to author, but usually involves something like $2^X$, reminiscent of related notations for power sets and the calculation for the number of elements in the power set and so on.  To draw a cube of dimension one higher than you are used to, draw the previous size cube... copy it... and then connect, such as is done in the picture below:

[image]

The coordinates in $n$-dimensional space can correspond to whether you *do* or *do not* include the corresponding elements in your particular element of the powerset.  The entry with coordinates all $0$ for instance corresponding to the empty set, and the coordinates all $1$ corresponding to the original set itself.

Using the language of boolean lattices, we find that the [join and meet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet) operations in lattices correspond neatly to the union and intersection operations of sets respectively.  Similarly, upsets and downsets in lattices correspond nicely to other concepts in set theory.

This is a very useful example to remember when beginning to study lattices and posets in general in greater detail.